# Where did I go wrong? Integration by parts

Tags: integration

So I was looking at the integral of $\int{f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df(x)}{dx})dx}$ and I got the following using the DI method (for those who don't know it search DI bprp on youtube):

choosing f(x) for D and $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df(x)}{dx})$ for I we get on the first row $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ for both D and I, and continuing another row (and switching the sign from + to -) we get $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df(x)}{dx})$ for D and f(x) for I, and by using the rules of DI method we would get:

$\int{f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df(x)}{dx})dx} = f(x)\cdot\frac{df(x)}{dx} -\int{f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df(x)}{dx})dx}$

by adding $\int{f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df(x)}{dx})dx}$ to both sides we get:

$2\int{f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df(x)}{dx})dx} = f(x)\cdot\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ and so:

$\int{f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df(x)}{dx})dx} = \frac{f(x)\cdot\frac{df(x)}{dx}}{2}$

but this is clearly wrong as even just looking at $f(x)=x^2 -> f'(x)=2x -> f''(x)=2$ we can see that the "formula" I got is wrong as on the integral side we get $2x^3/3$ and on the right-hand side we get $x^3$.

So I thought to myself maybe I used the DI method wrong and I tried normal I.B.P and so I wrote:

(1) $\int{f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df(x)}{dx})dx} = f(x)\cdot\frac{df(x)}{dx} - \int{\frac{df(x)}{dx}\cdot\frac{df(x)}{dx}dx}$

and if we look at that last integral and integrate it by parts we would get:

$\int{\frac{df(x)}{dx}\cdot\frac{df(x)}{dx}dx} = f(x)\cdot\frac{df(x)}{dx} - \int{f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df(x)}{dx})dx}$

plugging this back into (1) we get:

$\int{f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df(x)}{dx})dx} = f(x)\cdot\frac{df(x)}{dx} - \int{\frac{df(x)}{dx}\cdot\frac{df(x)}{dx}dx} = f(x)\cdot\frac{df(x)}{dx} - (f(x)\cdot\frac{df(x)}{dx} - \int{f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df(x)}{dx})dx}) = f(x)\cdot\frac{df(x)}{dx} - f(x)\cdot\frac{df(x)}{dx} - \int{f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df(x)}{dx})dx}$

So overall:

$2\int{f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df(x)}{dx})dx}=0 -> \int{f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df(x)}{dx})dx}=0$

Which is even more wrong ??? please tell me where I went wrong with both methods??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the DI method, you will get
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
+&f(x)&f^{\prime\prime}(x)\\
-&f^\prime(x)&f^{\prime}(x)\\
+&f^{\prime\prime}(x)&f(x)
\end{array}$$
And so
$$\int f(x)f^{\prime\prime}(x)\,\mathrm dx=f(x)f^\prime(x)-f^\prime(x)f(x)+\int f(x)f^{\prime\prime}(x)$$
which is true, but an useless equation. You have made sign errors in your attempt.

If you carefully go through your second solution as well, you will notice that you took the wrong sign in the last equation and so instead of the integral cancelling, it instead added up to give something like $2\int(\cdots)=0$.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: omg I'm so stupid thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my DI table: $$ \array { & \text D & & \text I \\ & --- & & --- \\ + & f ( x ) & & f ' ' ( x ) \\ & & \searrow \\ - & f ' ( x ) & & f ' ( x ) \\ & & \searrow \\ + & f ' ' ( x ) & & f ( x ) } $$

So the top row is $ + \int f ( x ) \, f ' ' ( x ) \, \mathrm d x $, which is the integral that we're evaluating.  Then next we follow the first arrow to get $ + f ( x ) \, f ' ( x ) $.  Then we follow the next arrow to get $ - f ' ( x ) \, f ( x ) $.  There are no more arrows, so we finish with $ + \int f ' ' ( x ) \, f ( x ) \, \mathrm d x $.

Conclusion: $$ \int f ( x ) \, f ' ' ( x ) \, \mathrm d x = f ( x ) \, f ' ( x ) - f ' ( x ) \, f ( x ) + \int f ' ' ( x ) \, f ( x ) \, \mathrm d x \text , $$ which is true but useless.

When you did this, it seems like you forgot to include the term from the second arrow.

When you did it the non-DI way, you neglected to distribute a minus sign.  The last term should have been $ - - = + $, but you left it $ - $.

Comment: thanks! I don't know how I missed that 